# Spark-Streaming Kafka Direct Streaming API & Parallelism

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I understood the automated mapping that exists between a Kafka Partition and a Spark RDD partition and ultimately Spark Task. However in order to properly Size My Executor (in number of Core) and therefore ultimately my node and cluster, I need to understand something that seems to be glossed over in the documentations.

In Spark-Streaming how does exactly work the **data consumption vs data processing vs task allocation**, in other words:

> 1. Does a corresponding **Spark task** to a **Kafka partition** both read
>      and process the data altogether ?

- The rational behind this question is that in the previous API, that
  is, the receiver based, a TASK was dedicated for receiving the data,
  meaning a number tasks slot of your executors were reserved for data
  ingestion and the other were there for processing.  This had an
  impact on how you size your executor in term of cores.
- Take for example the advise on how to launch spark-streaming with
  ***--master local***. Everyone would tell that in the case of spark streaming, 
  one should put ***local[2]*** minimum, because one of the 
  core, will be dedicated to running the long receiving task that never
  ends, and the other core will do the data processing.
- So if the answer is that in this case, the task does both the reading
  and the processing at once, then the question that follows, is that
  really smart, i mean, this sounds like asynchronous. We want to be
  able to fetch while we process so on the next processing the data is 
  already there. However if there only one core or more precisely to
  both read the data and process them, how can both be done in
  parallel, and how does that make things faster in general.
- My original understand was that, things would have remain somehow the
  same in the sense that, a task would be launch to read but that the
  processing would be done in another task. That would mean that, if
  the processing task is not done yet, we can still keep reading, until
  a certain memory limit.

Can someone outline with clarity what is exactly going on here ?

**EDIT1**

We don't even have to have this memory limit control. Just the mere fact of being able to fetch while the processing is going on and stopping right there. In other words, the two process should be asynchronous and the limit is simply to be one step ahead. To me if somehow this is not happening, i find it extremely strange that Spark would implement something that break performance as such.

Answer (score 2):

> Does a corresponding Spark task to a Kafka partition both read and
>   process the data altogether ?

The relationship is very close to what you describe, if by talking about a task we're referring to the part of the graph that reads from kafka up until a shuffle operation. The flow of execution is as follows:

1. Driver reads offsets from all kafka topics and partitions
2. Driver assigns each executor a topic and partition to be *read and processed*.
3. Unless there is a shuffle boundary operation, it is likely that Spark will optimize the entire execution of the partition on the same executor.

This means that a single executor will read a given `TopicPartition` and process the entire execution graph on it, unless we need to shuffle. Since a Kafka partition maps to a partition inside the `RDD`, we get that guarantee.

Structured Streaming takes this even further. In Structured Streaming, there is stickiness between the `TopicPartition` and the worker/executor. Meaning, if a given worker was assigned a `TopicPartition` it is likely to continue processing it for the entire lifetime of the application.

Comment: Would you have a reference to this: "Structured Streaming, there is stickiness between the TopicPartition and the worker/executor" ? I'm interested in learning more about that.

Comment: @maasg https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/external/kafka-0-10-sql/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/kafka010/KafkaSource.scala#L274

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov although you confirm part of what i suspected, you did not answer the performance question i had and i think i found the answer. It is Kafka new consumer API and its ability to do Prefetching and subsequently the fact that spark caches it. You can see more detail about the Prefetching here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-41%3A+KafkaConsumer+Max+Records#KIP-41:KafkaConsumerMaxRecords-Prefetching|

Comment: In other words, my problem was that it sounded not ok to me that you assign a Kafka partition to a Task in Spark, and that task read the partition and then process it following a specific batch interval time. Said like this, it is not performant, as the reading of the data and the processing of it are synchronous. It goes against the all current trend in data processing e.g. reactive stream processing. Today everyone goes with an approach were the 2 operation are too asynchronous process were the reactive approach shine on it with its automated back pressure and pull and push approach.

Comment: I was shocked to think that spark streaming was being synchronous about it. That is a task is a thread, and as such can only do one thing at a time. Either it fetch data or process that data. However thank god I discover that the Kafka underlying consumer API does a pre-fetching and spark streaming cache the created consumer. I believe that help with the performance issue i am mentioning. @Yuval Itzchakov Does it make sense ??

Comment: @MaatDeamon Which performance issue are you talking about? I'm not sure I follow. Spark distributes reading of offsets between multiple workers, that means you're concurrently reading from each partition. It is quite possible that a single task will read *and process* a set of Kafka meesages. Further, Spark makes sure the entire RDD is processed before continuing to the next batch. I'm not sure why you find that shocking, not all systems use asynchronous messaging to process data.

Comment: @MaatDeamon You need to elaborate more on your performance issue for me to understand. I don't think this has anything to do with Kafka prefetching.

Comment: "that means you're concurrently reading from each partition. It is quite possible that a single task will read and process a set of Kafka mesages." Let's first clarify that, to me it is not quite possible, it is what is happening: If you have a topic with 4 partitions, you will find yourself with an RDD with 4 partition, each partition will be handle by one task in an executor. How it is distributed among executor is beside the point. By handle, it is meant, the task will read the partition and process the data. That's the model as it is described. I am not sure why you say possibly ?

Comment: This being said, yes i have a problem with a task charge with both reading over the network and processing. This is slow full stop. That's why asynchronous processing was invented. You should be able to make the data available while the processing of the previous interval is going. It makes things faster. Now with the pre-fetching, i believe the issue is addressed

Comment: This is what is written in the link that i sent you: "The KafkaConsumer implements a prefetching optimization to improve throughput. Before returning a set of records to the user in poll(), the consumer will initiate the next round of fetches in order to pipeline the fetching overhead and message processing. While the consumer is processing the current batch of records, the broker can handle the consumer's fetch requests (including blocking for new data if fetch.min.bytes is configured). The idea is to have data already available when the consumer finishes processing and invokes poll() again."

Comment: Here is what is written in the Spark direct stream API: "The new Kafka consumer API will pre-fetch messages into buffers. Therefore it is important for performance reasons that the Spark integration keep cached consumers on executors (rather than recreating them for each batch), and prefer to schedule partitions on the host locations that have the appropriate consumers.

Comment: I think all of that enables to have somehow the next round of data available, whenever a task is currently processing data. If I understand all of that wrong, please explain, but that is what i meant. Hope i was clear enough :)